# printing out tuples from function

Tags: python

Im making this function that prints the index number with the item from the string but I need it to print out as tuples, for example

```
[(0, 'dog'), (1, 'pig'), (2, 'cow')]
```

how would I go about doing this? it just prints each out on one line so far.

this is my code so far.

```
def my_enumerate(items):
    """return a list of tuples where item is the i'th item """
    for item in items:
        index = items.index(item)    

        print(item, index)
my_enumerate(['dog', 'pig', 'cow'])
```

thank you

Comment: Uhhh, are you sure you have to *print* it? The docstring of the function says *"return a list of tuples"*.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel: `for i, animal in enumerate(items): print(i, animal)`.

Comment: `def my_enumerate(items): return list(enumerate(items))` ... for what it's worth - no need to capsulate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def my_enumerate(items):
    """return a list of tuples where item is the i'th item """
    l = []
    for index in range(len(items)):
        t = (index, items[index])
        l.append(t)
    return  l

res = my_enumerate(['x', 'x', 'x'])
print(res)
```

Comment: but with a  res = ['x', 'x', 'x'] , it says the index of each is 0 because they're all x's (the same) i assume? how do I fix that

Comment: @JulieG, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
def my_enumerate(items):
    print([(i, animal) for i, animal in enumerate(items)])
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason you are printing them one by one is that you are printing them one by one inside the loop, to get all of them at once you will need to create a list and print that at the end of the loop. there are several ways to go about this and m0nte-cr1st0 gave you the most legible one, ill give you something a little shorter:

```
def my_enumerate(items):
    return list(zip(range(len(items)), items))
```

zip lets you smoosh together 2 lists pairwise
this solution of course assumes you cant just use the built in `enumerate`

Answer (score 0):

In expression

```
print(list(enumerate(items)))
```

part `enumerate(['dog', 'pig', 'cow'])` will create an iterator over the list of tuples `[(0, 'dog'), (1, 'pig'), (2, 'cow')]` you want to print , so you can just create a list with this iterator and print it.